# Se dibuja mal InternalFrame dentro de JFrame con fondo

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, jframe, paint

tengo un problema que cuando quiero abrir un InternalFrame dentro de un JFrame con fondo (Ya sea una imagen o de un color) se ve mal y al pasarle el mouse por encima de los componentes van apareciendo, y si muevo la ventana el fondo del JFrame se va borrando, dejo unas fotos de referencia. Gracias desde ya

[image: Foto1]

[image: Foto 2]

[image: Foto 3]

Y dejo unos pedazos del codigo:

Este es el constructor del JFrame

```
public FrmMenu() {
    initComponents();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(1200, 769));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    
    this.setLayout(null);
    jDesktopPane_menu = new JDesktopPane();

    int ancho = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int alto = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    this.jDesktopPane_menu.setBounds(0, 0, ancho, (alto - 110));
    this.add(jDesktopPane_menu);

    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../img/ventas.png")).getImage());

    // Configurar un ComponentListener para el JFrame
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Acciones a realizar cuando se redimensiona el JFrame
            x = getWidth();
            y = getHeight()-100;
        }
    });
    
    jDesktopPane_menu.setOpaque(true);
}
```

Asi abro los internalFrame:

```
private void jMenuItem_gestionar_productosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                              
    InterProductos interProductos = new InterProductos();
    jDesktopPane_menu.add(interProductos);     
    interProductos.setVisible(true);
    

    int x = (this.x - interProductos.getWidth()) / 2;
    int y = (this.y - interProductos.getHeight()) / 2;
    interProductos.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y procurá mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión. No olvides que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_.

Comment: Un *JInternalFrame* deberías agregarlo a algún [*JLayeredPane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).